# After what level of editing should I just re-ask the question?

Tags: support, questions, edits

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59590914/c-sharp-can-i-set-a-checkboxes-name-with-a-string) a bit ago. However, when I was writing it I didn't see how chaotic it looked. After a lot of confusion, I decided to simplify the question. However, now the question does not have any line that is the same as the first variation of it (check the revision history of the question).

Should I re-ask the question?

Comment: One thing you could do, is to please make the letter I upper case when referring to yourself. That's basic English grammar, and if you can start remembering to hold down the shift key, that means less editing for me :).

Comment: English sure have weird rules that we don't have.. But sure if that's that important I'll try not to forget.

Comment: When it becomes a different question

Comment: @TylerH which would contradict NathanOliver's answer which adds the stipulation of "as long as it does not invalidate existing answers". However, I agree that the question shouldn't become a different question in general - because that also catches the situation where answers currently being written are invalidated.

Comment: @Gimby A question with no answers yet is a special kind of limbo. However, if you have enough time to edit a question so much before it gets an answer, you probably should be reviewing it more carefully before posting.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The rule is don't invalidate existing answers.  If your edit will do that, then it should be a new question.  If it doesn't then go ahead and edit.

In this case you've invalidated the answers so I suggest rolling back the edit and asking a new question.

Comment: Should we delete the old question then? It didn't concluded anyways and will not be used.

Comment: @aGoodFellow The question as is does not qualify for deletion.

Comment: When you say "will not be used", do you mean **you** will not use the old question?  If so, maybe not, but someone else might.